# CMake find_package path to package

Tags: cmake

Is there a variable that stores the path to the found package similar to the package version?

```
find_package(name)
message("name version: ${name_VERSION}") #something like this but only for path to package?
```

Comment: What do you mean by "path to package"? Path to the `XXXConfig.cmake` file which has been processed? If yes, then there is `XXX_DIR` variable which contains directory with that file.

Comment: That is what I meant, thank you, (consider writing an answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If corresponded `XXXConfig.cmake` file has been found in `find_package(XXX)` call, then variable `XXX_CONFIG` contains absolute path to that file.

Also, there is CACHE variable `XXX_DIR` which contains directory with the file. Because this is a cached variable, its value can be found in `CMakeCache.txt` file after running `cmake`.

More about `find_package` behavior can be found in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/find_package.html).